# wxPython session timeout

Tags: python, session, wxpython

I have a medium sized desktop application created with `wxPython`. I want to implement a `session` facility in this application. After some amount of time of inactivity, the application should log the user out and show login screen automatically. What will be the best way to accomplish this in `wxPython`?

The application uses `wxPython 2.8.12.1` with `Python 2.7` within `Windows 8, 7, XP`.

**EDIT 1**

Binding `EVT_MOTION` to `wx.Frame` and `wx.Panel` not working. It is working if I bind `EVT_MOTION` to all individual objects. Is there any way to get event bubbled to the outermost parent (`wx.Frame`)?

```
import wx

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, "Checking EVT_MOTION with Frame")

        panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        panel.SetSizer(sizer)

        sizer.Add(wx.Button(panel, -1, "Button 1"), 1, wx.EXPAND)
        sizer.Add(wx.Button(panel, -1, "Button 2"), 1, wx.EXPAND)
        sizer.Add(wx.Button(panel, -1, "Button 3"), 1, wx.EXPAND)

        self.Bind(event=wx.EVT_MOTION, handler=self.OnMotion)

        self.Show()

    def OnMotion(self, event):
        print "EVT_MOTION: " + str(event.GetEventObject())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a wx.Timer. You can restart it every time the user moves their mouse (wx.EVT_MOTION) or presses a key (wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN). I wrote up a tutorial on using wx.Timers that you might find helpful:

- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2009/08/25/wxpython-using-wx-timers/

Here's the one of the examples from that tutorial that implements a super simple wx.Timer:

```
import wx
import time

class MyForm(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "Timer Tutorial 1", 
                                   size=(500,500))

        # Add a panel so it looks the correct on all platforms
        panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)

        self.timer = wx.Timer(self)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.update, self.timer)

        self.toggleBtn = wx.Button(panel, wx.ID_ANY, "Start")
        self.toggleBtn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onToggle)

    def onToggle(self, event):
        btnLabel = self.toggleBtn.GetLabel()
        if btnLabel == "Start":
            print "starting timer..."
            self.timer.Start(1000)
            self.toggleBtn.SetLabel("Stop")
        else:
            print "timer stopped!"
            self.timer.Stop()
            self.toggleBtn.SetLabel("Start")

    def update(self, event):
        print "\nupdated: ",
        print time.ctime()

# Run the program
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    frame = MyForm().Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: I have many panels with many buttons and other controls. Most of them are already bound with some events. How can I achieve this without adding timer code for each control's events? Will it work if I directly bind key down and click events to outermost frame? But again I have some controls that stops the propagation of events.

Comment: I would just bind the EVT_MOTION event to the frame or top level panel. That should work for most things as I expect the user to move the mouse during the use of the application. Most timeouts are at least 5 minutes and typically 10 or 15, so this really shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it and will let you know the results :)

Comment: `EVT_MOTION` bound to `wx.Frame` or `wx.Panel` not working. Moving mouse over objects is not considered Frame's event and/or it is not bubbled to the parent. Check **EDIT 1** in question. Any help is appreciated.